# Using libcurl in multithreaded environment c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, curl, libcurl

I have created an `APIExecutor` class which should ideally be able to generate api requests and process the responses in a thread safe manner. Since I am on curl 7.29.0, I am using mutex locking/unlocking in the `ApiExecutor` constructor and destructor.

```
static size_t WriteCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}

class APIExecutor
{
    string mResponse;
    CURL *mCurl;
    static std::mutex mCurlMutex;

    APIExecutor()
    {
        std::mutex mCurlMutex;
        mCurlMutex.lock();
        mCurl = curl_easy_init();
    }
    ~APIExecutor()
    {
        std::mutex mCurlMutex;
        curl_easy_cleanup(mCurl);
        mCurlMutex.unlock();
    }

    std::string InvokeAPI(std::string& rest_url)
    {
        mResponse = "";
        //setting some more opts
        curl_easy_setopt(mCurl, CURLOPT_URL, rest_url.c_str()); 
        curl_easy_setopt(mCurl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);       
        curl_easy_setopt(mCurl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &mResponse);
        const CURLcode rc = curl_easy_perform(mCurl);
        return mResponse;
    }
}

APIExecutor executor;
boost::property_tree::ptree mResRoot;
std::vector<std::string> vecApis1;
std::vector<std::string> vecApis2;

void ReadResponse(std::string& ss)
{
    std::stringstream sstream;
    sstream << ss;

    /* Read json. */
    try {
        boost::property_tree::read_json(sstream, mResRoot);
    }
    catch (std::exception const& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        throw e.what();
    }
}
//Similarly we have testApi2() which iterates vecApis2
void testApi1()
{
    /*
    *In the actual use case, API URLs generated in each thread.
    *Using a pre-defined vecApis just for reference purpose
    */
    for(string& s : vecApis1)
    {
        string response;
        response = executor.InvokeAPI(s);
        cout << response << endl;
        
        try
        {
            ReadResponse(response);
        }
        catch (const std::exception& ex)
        {
            std::string s = "Error json parse failed :"  + std::string(ex.what());
            std::cout << __func__ << ":" << __LINE__ << " " << s << std::endl;
            throw std::runtime_error(s);
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            std::string s = "Error json parse failed ";
            std::cout << __func__ << ":" << __LINE__ << " " << s << std::endl;
            throw s.c_str();
        }   
    }
}

void popVec1()
{
    vecApis1.push_back("randomApiString1");
    vecApis1.push_back("randomApiString2");
    vecApis1.push_back("randomApiString3");
}
void popVec2()
{
    vecApis2.push_back("randomApiString4");
    vecApis2.push_back("randomApiString5");
    vecApis2.push_back("randomApiString6");
}

int main()
{
    popVec1();popVec2();
    thread t1(testApi1), t2(testApi2);
    t1.join(); t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Though I do see at least 2 `cout`s just before `curl_easy_perform` properly each time with the correct URL, the program terminates then and there only due to segmentation fault. It seems to me that though the serializing of curl calls is happening correctly due to locking the mutex in the constructor, `InvokeAPI` is still not thread safe.

Comment: After plenty of other trials, I ended up declaring a `thread_local` `CURL*` instance. With this, multi-threading works perfectly without any mutex, and Keep-Alive feature is working when setting `CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE` option to 1. If you are not using Keep-Alive, you should just have a local `CURL*` variable inside `InvokeAPI`.

Answer (score 0):

You lock and unlock the mutex in the constructor and destructor of `executor` .. of which there is a single instance. You want to make sure only one instance of `InvokeAPI` is running at once, so you need to acquire the mutex in `InvokeAPI`. Remove the lock and unlock calls from the constructor and destructor, as well as the useless `mCurlMutex` local variables. Make `mCurlMutex` non-static and change `InvokeAPI` as such:

```
    std::string InvokeAPI(std::string& rest_url)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{mCurlMutex};
        mResponse = "";
        //setting some more opts
        curl_easy_setopt(mCurl, CURLOPT_URL, rest_url.c_str()); 
        curl_easy_setopt(mCurl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);       
        curl_easy_setopt(mCurl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &mResponse);
        const CURLcode rc = curl_easy_perform(mCurl);
        return mResponse;
    }
```

Of course this entire answer is predicated on your insistence of having a single APIExecutor that wraps a single `CURL*`. You could just as well create a local `CURL*` inside `InvokeAPI` and not have to do this dance...

Comment: The whole ```InvokeAPI``` has will be executed multiple times in a loop therefore for efficiency, trying to reuse ```CURL*``` for the instance of ```APIExecutor``` and not initializing the ```CURL*``` per API call

Comment: That still does not stop you from creating one executor instance *per thread* and avoid all the extra pain that comes with multithreading. I also think you severely overestimate the cost of `curl_easy_init`.

Comment: The design is to have a single instance of ```APIExecutor``` per cpp file which will use that specific object to invoke the API. The function invoking the API will be invoked at most 2 threads at a time but that function could be invoked 1000 times within a short span, that's why insisting on having one ```CURL*``` per instance